# IntelliJ IDE history of local changes for specifc line

Tags: intellij-idea

The history of the class will show the changes made for that class. How can I see the changes made for a specific line of a code when the history list is too long. I mean instead of going through the list is there a feature where I can filter the history list?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it would be useful. Code is a living thing, the line numbers of some piece of code change constantly.

Comment: Do you mean local history of Version Control history? It's possible to show history for a line in Git (Git - Show history for selection )

Comment: @y.bedrov: No, I am not talking git. The IntelliJ has a history feature where you can see changes made to a file.

Comment: @Andronicus: Yes, thats for sure. But somehow I want see histiry made for that line or piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a IntelliJ feature, where you can see the local history for your selection.

**Select something in the editor > right click > Local History > Show History for Selection**